# How to customize the pager in jquery image slider

Tags: jquery, css, bxslider

I'm using [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) and [lightSlider](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/) and I want the pager to look like a curve (half a circle) not inline as it designed

I searched a lot and found nothing

[image]

Something like in the picture
without the arrow

any ideas ?

Comment: Why are you using two plugins? Which does your question involve? Generally speaking, SO requires that you make an effort and then post what you've tried.

Comment: i use one of them but they are generally the same, also i don't know how to do that i need some instructions
@isherwood

Comment: A basic understanding of HTML and CSS would allow you to customize the bullets as you see fit. The only complication I see is if the number of bullets varies, in which case you'd have to do some math to position them.